# use Boost python in Qt creator

Tags: c++, python, qt, boost

I want to embedded python code in Qt C++ code. I create a console Qt app for test.

My `.pro` is

```
SOURCES += main.cpp
LIBS = -lboost_python -lpython27

HEADERS += /usr/include/python2.7
```

My `main.cpp` file is

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

But I found I can't build this program.

error message is:

```
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50: 
Error:pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
```

I googled this problem, but havn't got answer.

How to configure Qt I want embedded Python code in My Qt C++ program?

Comment: Do you have the python developer package installed on your system?  Generally, package maintainers only distribute `pyconfig.h` in the developer package.

Comment: I can find `pyconfig.h` in `/usr/include/python2.7` I had install `libpython2.7` in `Ubuntu`

Answer (score 3):

it's INCLUDEPATH, not HEADERS in .pro file.

Answer (score 1):

You must install python developer package at first.
In Ubuntu you can use `apt-get` as the following:

`apt-get install python2.7-dev`